# Makefile: Link several *.a to executable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I try to write a Makefile that takes several static libraries that have been created before and link the to an executable. Although one libary has a `main`-routine.

I get the error:

```
/lib/../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [dockSIM_gcc_release] Error 1
```

I tried it with just linking the library that has the `main` routine but the error stays the same and comes directly after invoking `make`.

The Makefile:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
RM=/bin/rm -f
CXX=g++
PROGNAME=dockSIM_gcc_release

DEFINES=-DDOCKSIM_VERBOSE=FALSE -DNDEBUG -DPRINT_LOG_MSG=0 -DPRINT_DEBUG_MSG=0

LDFLAGS = -fopenmp -g -O3 -std=c++11 -mavx -mstackrealign -fstrict-aliasing

LIBS= -lnagc_mkl -lm -L../externalCode -lpardiso500-GNU481-X86-64 -lacml 

FILENAMES = commandInterpreter_lib.a 

OBJNAMES =


all: $(PROGNAME)


$(PROGNAME): $(FILENAMES)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(DEFINES) -o $(PROGNAME) $(FILENAMES) 


clean:
    $(RM) *.mo *.ho *.o $(PROGNAME) core *~ 

test:
    echo $(FILENAMES) 
showlibs:
    echo $(LIBS)
```

The flags are compatible with those that were used to compile the code.

g++ 4.9.3 is used.

Signature of the main-Routine:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Thanks for help and kind regards.

Comment: Which library has the `main`? Is it `commandInterpreter_lib.a` or the unused  `nagc_mkl`, `pardiso500-GNU481-X86-64` or `acml` libraries. (Unused, because `$(LIBS)` is not used when linking, it seems)

Comment: The commandInterpreter_lib has the main. The LIBS are left out intentionally to have a minimal example.

Comment: And it *absolutely* doesn't have anything to do with your problem?  You're linking with a C++ compiler. Was everything else also compiled with that same compiler?

Comment: It is a project mixed of gcc compiled c and g++ compiled cpp files.

UPDATE:
I just recognized that the main is found, when the library is compiled with Debug-configuration

Comment: Well the difference between debug and any other configuration for
building the library is absent from the information you have posted, so if any problem remains you would
need to show us that difference.

Comment: Can you please reformulate. I don't understand what you need now.

Comment: It's very unusual to have main inside a library.  But in any event, if it works in debug but not non-debug, then you should look at the command line that make is invoking when you link with debug, that works, and compare it to the command line that make is invoking when you link without debug, that doesn't work.

Comment: @MadScientist
Yes I know that this is not the best way, but in this case it is the only way within reasonable time, because the original project, that contains the main has a very complex and not really changeable Makefile and its programmer left.
We already thought that the compiler is perhaps removing the main routine because it is normally not part of a static lib and that this is the reason why the Debug works. The only obvious difference I see are the compiler flags, especially O0 vs O3.

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess what's wrong.

There is more to linking a static library than just a convenient bundle of object files to reduce command line length.  In addition to that, the linker only links in object files which it thinks are needed.  An object file is needed if there's some undefined symbol that the linker is looking for, that is contained in that object.  If there's no symbol that the linker needs in the object, then the linker ignores the object and doesn't link it.

The normal way to build a program is to have the main program listed as object files on the command line: the linker always links every object file.  This gives the linker a set of symbols which are defined (by the object files) and undefined (things the object files use but that aren't defined by them).  Then the linker will go through the libraries on the link line and add in object files that resolve undefined symbols.  These object files in turn may have other undefined symbols that the linker will need to resolve later, etc.

All I can guess is that by not having any object files on your link line, the linker doesn't see the object file in the library containing main as needed and so it doesn't link it.

I don't know why building with debug vs. non-debug makes a difference.

I didn't understand your comment about why you need to do things this way: even if the person who knew about this left, someone will need to learn about it to maintain the software.

In any event you have a few options.

One simple one is to use the "ar" program to extract out the object file containing main and link it directly: in addition to adding objects to libraries `ar` can extract them.  Then you can link that object directly.  See the man page for `ar`.

Another would be to look at the documentation for your compiler and linker and find flags that will force it to include the entire library, not just the unresolved symbols in the library.  For the GCC/binutils linker, for example, you can pass `-Wl,--whole-archive` before the libraries you want to be fully included on the command line, then `-Wl,--no-whole-archive` after them to turn off that feature.

Comment: Hey MadScientist. We will try what you have written. At the moment we found that using gcc 4.8. solves our problem while it does not work for 4.9 and all versions above while the Intel compiler works in all versions.

Yes some other person will have to look at this code in the future if it will be further developed, but I only need exactly this version to combine it with my code and don't have the time during my phd studies to modify and understand code and makefiles that I am only using as black box ;)